# Unity ads not working on real device

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, ads

In my current Unity program I wanted to implement ads. The ads do work in the Unity editor when I run the game, but when I try to run the ads on my iPhone 7 or iPad Air, there are no ads showing up. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

void Start()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize("Appstore-id");
}

bool gameHasEnded = false;

public float restartDelay = 1f;
public float addDelay = 1f;

public GameObject completeLevelUI;

public void CompleteLevel ()
{
    completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);
    Invoke("ShowAdd", addDelay);
}

public void EndGame()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
    {
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Debug.Log("Game over");
        Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
    }

}

public void ShowAdd()
{

    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show ();
    }
}

void Restart()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}

}
```

Comment: @Eddge https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html `Invoke` takes a 2nd argument, which dictates how much time should pass (at minimum) before the method is called.

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen yea I realized that haha

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the way I fixed it was a recursive function until the ad was ready. Something like:

```
IEnumerator ShowAd()
{
    yield return new waitForSeconds(1);
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show ();
    }
    else { StartCoroutine(ShowAd()); }
}
```

This way it will call the method until the ad is ready to show.
Also, make sure you have test (or debug) mode enabled on Unity Ads Settings.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I am going to try it out and see if it works for mee as well.

Comment: I still get an error, even when I change it to ShowAdd

Comment: @GriffinTeurlings instead of calling invoke are you calling `StartCoroutine` instead?

Comment: [Not related to the question]: @Mykod wouldn't it be enough to `yield return ShowAd();` in the else block as we're already inside a coroutine at that point?

Comment: I have just tested if the ads were working on my phone after installing the version of my project, but they are still not working. The other thing I also noticed was that the UIButtons in my pause menu are not working on my phone either, but they do work in the Unity editor.

Comment: @AndreasHassing probably, haven’t tested it, though.

Comment: The buttons do work now, I just had to change to change the navigation from none to automatic. But the advertisements still do not work. Do you know how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option besides recursively starting an IEnumerator:

```
IEnumerator ShowAd() 
{
    while(!Advertisement.isReady()) 
    {
        yield return new waitForSeconds(1);
    }
    Advertisement.Show();
}
```